# How do I get end of life data for all Ubuntu releases programatically

Tags: server, python

Is there an API that is provided by Ubuntu to get end-of-life date for all past and present releases of Ubuntu - like the data on [wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) but via an API ?

Also, I'm already aware about third party websites providing this data, but I would rather get it from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 12):

The package [`distro-info-data`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/all/distro-info-data) contains a file named [`/usr/share/distro-info/ubuntu.csv`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/all/distro-info-data/filelist). The full [up-to-date contents of this](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/distro-info-data/tree/ubuntu.csv?h=ubuntu%2Fdevel) file are like this:

```plaintext
version,codename,series,created,release,eol,eol-server,eol-esm
4.10,Warty Warthog,warty,2004-03-05,2004-10-20,2006-04-30
5.04,Hoary Hedgehog,hoary,2004-10-20,2005-04-08,2006-10-31
5.10,Breezy Badger,breezy,2005-04-08,2005-10-12,2007-04-13
6.06 LTS,Dapper Drake,dapper,2005-10-12,2006-06-01,2009-07-14,2011-06-01
6.10,Edgy Eft,edgy,2006-06-01,2006-10-26,2008-04-26
7.04,Feisty Fawn,feisty,2006-10-26,2007-04-19,2008-10-19
7.10,Gutsy Gibbon,gutsy,2007-04-19,2007-10-18,2009-04-18
8.04 LTS,Hardy Heron,hardy,2007-10-18,2008-04-24,2011-05-12,2013-05-09
8.10,Intrepid Ibex,intrepid,2008-04-24,2008-10-30,2010-04-30
9.04,Jaunty Jackalope,jaunty,2008-10-30,2009-04-23,2010-10-23
9.10,Karmic Koala,karmic,2009-04-23,2009-10-29,2011-04-30
10.04 LTS,Lucid Lynx,lucid,2009-10-29,2010-04-29,2013-05-09,2015-04-30
10.10,Maverick Meerkat,maverick,2010-04-29,2010-10-10,2012-04-10
11.04,Natty Narwhal,natty,2010-10-10,2011-04-28,2012-10-28
11.10,Oneiric Ocelot,oneiric,2011-04-28,2011-10-13,2013-05-09
12.04 LTS,Precise Pangolin,precise,2011-10-13,2012-04-26,2017-04-28,2017-04-28,2019-04-28
12.10,Quantal Quetzal,quantal,2012-04-26,2012-10-18,2014-05-16
13.04,Raring Ringtail,raring,2012-10-18,2013-04-25,2014-01-27
13.10,Saucy Salamander,saucy,2013-04-25,2013-10-17,2014-07-17
14.04 LTS,Trusty Tahr,trusty,2013-10-17,2014-04-17,2019-04-25,2019-04-25,2024-04-25
14.10,Utopic Unicorn,utopic,2014-04-17,2014-10-23,2015-07-23
15.04,Vivid Vervet,vivid,2014-10-23,2015-04-23,2016-02-04
15.10,Wily Werewolf,wily,2015-04-23,2015-10-22,2016-07-28
16.04 LTS,Xenial Xerus,xenial,2015-10-22,2016-04-21,2021-04-21,2021-04-21,2026-04-23
16.10,Yakkety Yak,yakkety,2016-04-21,2016-10-13,2017-07-20
17.04,Zesty Zapus,zesty,2016-10-13,2017-04-13,2018-01-13
17.10,Artful Aardvark,artful,2017-04-13,2017-10-19,2018-07-19
18.04 LTS,Bionic Beaver,bionic,2017-10-19,2018-04-26,2023-05-31,2023-05-31,2028-04-26
18.10,Cosmic Cuttlefish,cosmic,2018-04-26,2018-10-18,2019-07-18
19.04,Disco Dingo,disco,2018-10-18,2019-04-18,2020-01-23
19.10,Eoan Ermine,eoan,2019-04-18,2019-10-17,2020-07-17
20.04 LTS,Focal Fossa,focal,2019-10-17,2020-04-23,2025-05-29,2025-05-29,2030-04-23
20.10,Groovy Gorilla,groovy,2020-04-23,2020-10-22,2021-07-22
21.04,Hirsute Hippo,hirsute,2020-10-22,2021-04-22,2022-01-20
21.10,Impish Indri,impish,2021-04-22,2021-10-14,2022-07-14
22.04 LTS,Jammy Jellyfish,jammy,2021-10-14,2022-04-21,2027-06-01,2027-06-01,2032-04-21
22.10,Kinetic Kudu,kinetic,2022-04-21,2022-10-20,2023-07-20
23.04,Lunar Lobster,lunar,2022-10-20,2023-04-20,2024-01-25
```

You can look also at the [`distro-info`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/distro-info.1.html) command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirtry (100% in the spirit of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3821009)) bash script for which all credits go to [FedKad](https://askubuntu.com/users/855322/fedkad) for posting [their answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1464376/956809):

```
$ cat get-ubuntu-csv.sh
base=http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/distro-info-data/
latest_ver=$(curl -s $base|grep -o 'distro-info-data_[^t]\+tar.xz'|sort|tail -n1)
curl -s $base/$latest_ver|tar -xJO distro-info-data/ubuntu.csv
$ ./get-ubuntu-csv.sh
version,codename,series,created,release,eol,eol-server,eol-esm
4.10,Warty Warthog,warty,2004-03-05,2004-10-20,2006-04-30
5.04,Hoary Hedgehog,hoary,2004-10-20,2005-04-08,2006-10-31
5.10,Breezy Badger,breezy,2005-04-08,2005-10-12,2007-04-13
6.06 LTS,Dapper Drake,dapper,2005-10-12,2006-06-01,2009-07-14,2011-06-01
6.10,Edgy Eft,edgy,2006-06-01,2006-10-26,2008-04-26
7.04,Feisty Fawn,feisty,2006-10-26,2007-04-19,2008-10-19
7.10,Gutsy Gibbon,gutsy,2007-04-19,2007-10-18,2009-04-18
8.04 LTS,Hardy Heron,hardy,2007-10-18,2008-04-24,2011-05-12,2013-05-09
8.10,Intrepid Ibex,intrepid,2008-04-24,2008-10-30,2010-04-30
9.04,Jaunty Jackalope,jaunty,2008-10-30,2009-04-23,2010-10-23
9.10,Karmic Koala,karmic,2009-04-23,2009-10-29,2011-04-30
10.04 LTS,Lucid Lynx,lucid,2009-10-29,2010-04-29,2013-05-09,2015-04-30
10.10,Maverick Meerkat,maverick,2010-04-29,2010-10-10,2012-04-10
11.04,Natty Narwhal,natty,2010-10-10,2011-04-28,2012-10-28
11.10,Oneiric Ocelot,oneiric,2011-04-28,2011-10-13,2013-05-09
12.04 LTS,Precise Pangolin,precise,2011-10-13,2012-04-26,2017-04-28,2017-04-28,2019-04-28
12.10,Quantal Quetzal,quantal,2012-04-26,2012-10-18,2014-05-16
13.04,Raring Ringtail,raring,2012-10-18,2013-04-25,2014-01-27
13.10,Saucy Salamander,saucy,2013-04-25,2013-10-17,2014-07-17
14.04 LTS,Trusty Tahr,trusty,2013-10-17,2014-04-17,2019-04-25,2019-04-25,2024-04-25
14.10,Utopic Unicorn,utopic,2014-04-17,2014-10-23,2015-07-23
15.04,Vivid Vervet,vivid,2014-10-23,2015-04-23,2016-02-04
15.10,Wily Werewolf,wily,2015-04-23,2015-10-22,2016-07-28
16.04 LTS,Xenial Xerus,xenial,2015-10-22,2016-04-21,2021-04-21,2021-04-21,2026-04-23
16.10,Yakkety Yak,yakkety,2016-04-21,2016-10-13,2017-07-20
17.04,Zesty Zapus,zesty,2016-10-13,2017-04-13,2018-01-13
17.10,Artful Aardvark,artful,2017-04-13,2017-10-19,2018-07-19
18.04 LTS,Bionic Beaver,bionic,2017-10-19,2018-04-26,2023-05-31,2023-05-31,2028-04-26
18.10,Cosmic Cuttlefish,cosmic,2018-04-26,2018-10-18,2019-07-18
19.04,Disco Dingo,disco,2018-10-18,2019-04-18,2020-01-23
19.10,Eoan Ermine,eoan,2019-04-18,2019-10-17,2020-07-17
20.04 LTS,Focal Fossa,focal,2019-10-17,2020-04-23,2025-05-29,2025-05-29,2030-04-23
20.10,Groovy Gorilla,groovy,2020-04-23,2020-10-22,2021-07-22
21.04,Hirsute Hippo,hirsute,2020-10-22,2021-04-22,2022-01-20
21.10,Impish Indri,impish,2021-04-22,2021-10-14,2022-07-14
22.04 LTS,Jammy Jellyfish,jammy,2021-10-14,2022-04-21,2027-06-01,2027-06-01,2032-04-21
22.10,Kinetic Kudu,kinetic,2022-04-21,2022-10-20,2023-07-20
23.04,Lunar Lobster,lunar,2022-10-20,2023-04-20,2024-01-25
$
```